# Bash scripting, regex in if statement

Tags: regex, bash

I'm pretty new to bash scripting and regexp and have a question.
I want to check to see if my variable `$name` starts with a-d, e-h, i-l etc and do some stuff accordingly. If the string starts with "the." or "The." it should check the first letter after the period.

My problem is that if `$name` consists of "the.anchor" both the a-d0-9 and q-t will be true. Do you guys have any idea what's wrong?

```
if [[ $name =~ ^([tT]he\.)?[a-dA-D0-9]+ ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi

if [[ $name =~ ^([tT]he\.)?[e-hE-H]+ ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi

if [[ $name =~ ^([tT]he\.)?[i-lI-L]+ ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi

if [[ $name =~ ^([tT]he\.)?[m-pM-P]+ ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi

if [[ $name =~ ^([tT]he\.)?[q-tQ-T]+ ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi

if [[ $name =~ ^([tT]he\.)?[u-wU-W]+ ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi

if [[ $name =~ ^([tT]he\.)?[x-zX-Z]+ ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to fix my problem by using elif statements and putting the q-t part as the last one

Answer (score 2):

Your first part it optional:

```
([tT]he\.)?
```

So `the.anchor` matches the pattern `^([tT]he\.)?[a-dA-D0-9]+` because the `the.` matches `` `^([tT]he\.)? `` and the `a` matches `[a-dA-D0-9]+`. It matches `^([tT]he\.)?[q-tQ-T]+` because `^([tT]he\.)?` is optional an `t` matches `[q-tQ-T]+`. Note not the whole input is consumed by the second pattern, in fact only the first character is grabbed.

You can verify this by having bash echo the match:

```
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
```

Which should print `the.anchor` in the first case and `t` in the second.

You do not have an end anchor on the pattern so only part of the input needs to be matched. If you made the second pattern `^([tT]he\.)?[q-tQ-T]+$` then it would not match.

Alternatively you could make the the first part possessive - `^([tT]he\.)?+`. This will mean that if the engine matches the first expression it will not be unmatched. In the latter case `^([tT]he\.)?+` will grab the `the.` and then not release it when `[q-tQ-T]+` fails; this will cause the match to fail.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If I change the q-t to ^([tT]he\.)?[q-tQ-T]+$ it wont match if name is "the.tally"

Comment: @JonnyQuest no, it will not. You could also make the first part possessive so that if it is matched it will not be backtracked.

Comment: Found an "answer" to my question. Will accept my own answer in 2 days when I can. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think the `?` can be removed as the `if` statement is already doing the test.  The `+` matches the preceding item at least once and would only be needed if you want to match more than one instance of the letters.

You can do it like this:

```
if [[ $name =~ ^[tT]he\.[a-dA-D0-9] ]]; then
    do some stuff
fi
```

The condition will only return true if the first character after `^[tT]he\.` is `[a-dA-D0-9]`.

However, I tend to think `case` is a cleaner solution than `if` statements when matching lists of characters against variables.

```
case $name in
    [tT]he\.[a-dA-D0-9]*)
        do some stuff
        ;;
esac
```